# How to enlarge the 'free memory'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, out-of-memory, raspberry-pi3

I use colcon tools to build fastRTPS source code, During build process, the terminal will hung up there, and finally output some error message.

Before build code, In one terminal, I use command 'free -m' to check memory information, When the value of column 'free memory' reduce to very litte. The other terminal that execute build command will hung there. It should be not enough free memory to use, how can i solve this?

```
Before build code:
        total    used    free    shared    buff/cache    available
Mem:    912     124    700        4          87        768
Swap:   0       0      0

The last time ‘free -m’ was executed:
        total    used    free    shared    buff/cache   available
Mem:    912      820     4        4          87         72
Swap:   0        0       0
```

- **One terminal error message:**

```
ubuntu@raspberrypi:~/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/Fast-RTPS$ colcon build
Starting >>> fastrtps
[Processing: fastrtps]                            
[Processing: fastrtps]                                     
[Processing: fastrtps]                                       
[Processing: fastrtps]                                       
[Processing: fastrtps]                                       
--- stderr: fastrtps                                         
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [src/cpp/CMakeFiles/fastrtps.dir/rtps/writer/StatefulWriter.cpp.o] Error 4
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [src/cpp/CMakeFiles/fastrtps.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< fastrtps   [ Exited with code 2 ]
```

- **The other terminal error message:**

```
[76834.368716]Out of memory: Kill process 21298(cclplus) score 233 or sacrifice child
[76834.406051]Killed process 21298(cclplus) total-vm:251188KB, anon-rss:217952KB, file-rss:0KB, shmem-rss:0KB
```

Comment: You could enable a swap partition. It's very slow. You could also Cross compile on a stronger machine

Comment: Having no swap at all is usually not a great idea.

Comment: Ok， I will google how to make a swap partition, try to see whether it can solve this. Thank you guys. :)

Comment: @ThomasSablik [zram is much faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/499485/44425). Use it instead of a swap partition. Keep a small swap partition (if necessary) just in case

Answer (score 1):

1. you may always restart the build process and eventually get it to the completion.
2. `make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....` sounds like you're running several compilation processes, try to disable that, remove `-j N` from `make` command, leaving only one compilation thread.
3. get the Pi4 with 4Gb of memory

enabling swap won't help, you just don't have enough memory, and using swap will make it crawl for 20 minutes before dying instead of just dying and getting restarted.

---

ok, answering some of the questions in comments. I suspect the parallel compilation not only when I see `*** waiting for unfinished jobs`, but also when I see:

```
Starting >>> fastrtps
[Processing: fastrtps]
[Processing: fastrtps]
[Processing: fastrtps]
[Processing: fastrtps]
[Processing: fastrtps]
```

Please, check whatever build system you use, how to restrict parallel compilation to a single process.

Comment: When the terminal hung there for a long time, i have to use CTRL-C to terminate it, so the ***waiting for unfinished jobs...  output maybe because this.   As for restart the build process, it's not work, because the result always the same: build process just hung there.

Comment: @lobby added more info the to answer

Comment: I create a swap partition, it slowly, but it truely can success finally. I also follow your advice to try this:

<$ export  MAKEFLAGS='-j1'
 && $ colcon build>

 But the output message just like before. I wonder those [processing:fastrtps] means not only one process participate build? If so, why <export  MAKEFLAGS='-j1'> not take effect.

Comment: @lobby glad you have succeeded. if you find my answer useful, please upvote =)

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi is fixed-memory board, you can't add memory like you do on PCs and laptops. So there are two common solutions to this:

- Add swap partition or file - this will slow down things, because memory pages will be read/written to disk often, but still will increase available memory.
- Use cross-compiler on a stronger machine - you can build software on another machine, i.e PC, laptop, physical or cloud server using cross-compiler, i.e compiler that runs on one platform, but compiles for another platform.

Other people also suggest here that you can try buying another most recent RPi with 4 gb memory, but I'd recommend to use cross-compiler.